# Administrative places with openstreetmap

Tags: geolocation, openstreetmap, overpass-api, nominatim

I'm having alot of problems understanding the queries of the overpass-turbo api

I am trying to get all the provinces of every country in the world.
Or all the provinces of 1 certain country.
I think the province in this api is called an administrative boundary but I'm not sure

For example in Belgium it is:
Henegouwen
Luik
Luxemburg
Namen
Waals-Brabant
Antwerpen
Limburg
Oost-Vlaanderen
Vlaams-Brabant
West-Vlaanderen

If any of you guys have an idea how to form the good query for this, thanks !

Comment: Your question is not very specific, it doesn't even include the query you are trying to improve. Please fix your question and provide more details.

Furthermore, in order to download the correct administrative boundary you have to determine the corresponding `admin_level` first. This is country-specific. See [admin_level](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dadministrative#admin_level) in the OSM wiki for more information.

Comment: Unless you have your own Overpass API instance, I'd suggest to look at alternatives, like processing the OSM planet yourself, or specific sites, like https://wambachers-osm.website/boundaries/. By the way, the correct name for the API is "Overpass API". overpass turbo is the name of a web frontend.